# The existence of (non-rectangular) two dimensional Gray code

Tags: coding-theory

A *Gray code* consists of $n$-bit distinct strings $s_1,s_2, \ldots,s_N$ such that each $s_i$ and $s_{i+1}$ differs by one bit.
For example: $000, 001, 010, 011, 111, 110, 101, 100$.
It is known that we can have $N=2^n$ for every integer $n$.

A *two-dimensional Gray code* consists of $m*n$ strings $s_{i,j}$ for each $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$, such that each $s_{i,j}$ and $s_{i+1,j}$ differs by one bit, each $s_{i,j}$ and $s_{i,j+1}$ differs by one bit, and each $s_{i,j}$ and $s_{i+1,j+1}$ differs by two bits.
For example, the following is a $4*4$ Gray code using the optimal $\log_2 4*4=4$ bits.

0000, 0100, 1100, 1000

0001, 0101, 1101, 1001

0011, 0111, 1111, 1011

0010, 0110, 1110, 1010

It is not hard to construct $m*n$ 2d-gray codes using $\log mn + O(1)$ bits. My question is, if the "coordinates" $(i,j)$ does not form a rectangle (say, they lie arbitrarily on a grid), then is there an (almost) optimal 2d Gray code?
That is, given $N$ coordinates $X=\{(i,j)\}$, can we construct a 2d Gray code for each $s_{i,j}$ using only $\log N+O(1)$ bits, for any $N$ and $X$?

Comment: Nice question. Where is this applicable?

Comment: Are holes between the $s_{i,j}$ allowed? (and - for example - the codes for $s_{i,j}$, $s_{i+2,j+2}$ must have hamming distance 4)

Comment: @Turbo I think it would have some application in succinct encoding.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi What do you mean by holes? In my mind the subgraph of a grid (induced by the coordinates) is connected, but there could be $(i,j)\in X$ and $(i+1,j)\notin X$.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi the property you said does not hold when $(i+1,j),(i+2,j),(i+1,j+1),(i+2,j+1)\notin X$.

Comment: ok, I was only asking if the points in the grid graph must be connected; and how many different bits must have $s_{1,1}$ and $s_{3,3}$ if they are both in $X$, but $s_{2,2}$ is not in $X$ (the term hamming distance that I used is not correct)